# Adobe AIR bar code scanner

Tags: android, mobile, air, camera, barcode

I am developing an AIR mobile application. I want to implement bar code scanner in my Adobe AIR mobile application .

Is there any samples available? Is it possible?

Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZXing (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has an actionscript implementation.

You need to be aware that not all Android handsets natively support autofocus, including some modern ones such as the S2 (check out the Adobe forums for more info).